# Problems with old ggplot script giving a blank graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a simple bar graph, and repeating an old script with some simple data, but it refuses to return a graph.

Here's `dput` of the data frame:

```
papers <- structure(list(YEAR = c(1957, 1970, 1981, 1982, 1987, 1988, 1990, 
1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018), count = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 13L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-27L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here's the ggplot script:

```
ggplot(papers, aes(x=YEAR,y=count)) + 
scale_y_continuous(limit=c(0,20),expand=c(0, 0)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1955,1965,1975,1985,1995,2005,2015),
                   labels=c(1955,1965,1975,1985,1995,2005,2015)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10)) +
theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "grey50")) +
annotate("text",x=1948,y=18.5,label="ALL AREAS",
         family="arial",size=5.5,hjust=0,color="black")
```

[image]

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `?theme`

> panel.border  :
>   border around plotting area, drawn on top of plot so that it covers tick marks and grid lines. This should be used with fill=NA (element_rect; inherits from rect)

So your code works fine and all that must be changed is

```
theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "grey50", fill = NA))
```

[image]